# Strange slice behaviour

Tags: go, slice

I am trying to implement BFS algorithm for finding all paths (from src and dest) in a graph. I am using a slice to simulate a queue, but the slice gets corrupted (the append didn't work as expected) when I append to it more than one elements in the for cycle. I have no idea why. I am new in GoLand

```
// GetPathsFromCache retrieve information from loaded jsons in the cache
func (cache *ModelsDataCache) GetPathsFromCache(modelUrn, selectedElement, targetType, authToken string, modelJSONs *ModelJSONs) []systemdetection.GraphPath {

    result := make([]systemdetection.GraphPath, 0)

    //create the queue which stores the paths
    q := make([]Path, 0)

    //Path to store the current path
    var currentPath Path
    currentPath.path = append(currentPath.path, selectedElement)
    q = append(q, currentPath)


    for len(q) > 0 {


        currentPath = q[0] //get top
        q = q[1:]


        lastInThePath := currentPath.path[len(currentPath.path)-1]
        connectedToTheCurrent := cache.GetConnectionsFromCache(modelUrn, lastInThePath, authToken, modelJSONs)

        lastInPathType := modelJSONs.Elements[lastInThePath].Type

        if lastInPathType == targetType {
            //cache.savePath(currentPath, &result)

            var newPath systemdetection.GraphPath
            newPath.Target = lastInThePath
            newPath.Path = currentPath.path[:]
            newPath.Distance = 666
            result = append(result, newPath)
        }


        for _, connected := range connectedToTheCurrent {
            if cache.isNotVisited(connected, currentPath.path) {


                var newPathN Path

                newPathN.path = currentPath.path
                newPathN.path = append(newPathN.path, connected)

                q = append(q, newPathN)
            }
        }

    }

    return result

}
```

Comment: This code is filled with debugging statements, and missing enough context to actually run it. Can you try updating the quoted code to offer a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Comment: What do you mean by *"the append didn't work as expected"*? What result did you expect and what actual result did you get?

Comment: Well, just before I am creating the newPathN variable, I logged the queue's content and before I append I saw that the last few elements are not what they supposed to be. What actually fixed my issue was replacing "newPathN.path = currentPath.path" with iteration over the second one and append element after element. I am new in go lang, but I guess the problem was in my re-slicing of the queue...

Answer (score -1):

You may not be using `make` correctly. `make` for a slice takes two arguments, length and (optional) capacity:

```
make([]T, len, cap)
```

Len is the starting number of elements it contains, capacity is the number of elements it *could* contain without expanding. More on [A Tour of Go](https://tour.golang.org/moretypes/11).

Visually:

```
make([]string, 5) #=> ["", "", "", "", ""]
make([]string, 0, 5) #=> [] (but the underlying array can hold 5 elements)
```

`append` adds to the end of the array, so following the same example:

```
arr1 := make([]string, 5) #=> ["", "", "", "", ""]
arr1 = append(arr1, "foo") #=> ["", "", "", "", "", "foo"] 

arr2 := make([]string, 0, 5) #=> []
arr2 = append(arr2, "foo") #=> ["foo"] (underlying array can hold 4 more elements before expanding)
```

You are creating slices of a length and then appending to the end, meaning the first N elements of your slice are the zero value. Change your `make([]T, N)` to `make([]T, 0, N)`.

Here's a link to the Go Playground showing the difference: https://play.golang.org/p/ezoUGPHqSRj

Comment: The two `make`s I see are both `make(T, 0)`, it would be better if they had a capacity but it's *not* "definitely a bug".

Comment: If that 0 is actually 0, yes. However, given the number of edits, I don't think it's fair to assume the OP has the code exactly as it's currently written.